# mysql database no space available

Tags: mysql, directory-structure

I was restoring a **200 GB** database into a newly installed *RHEL* machine. However, while restoring I ran into `no space available` issue.

Is it possible to change the directory where the databases are stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I was able to verify that it was related to space issue only using the below `mysql` query.

```
mysql -uUSER -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_Name LIKE "%dir"'
```

The above command returned me the output as,

```
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name             | Value                      |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| basedir                   | /usr                       |
| character_sets_dir        | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
| datadir                   | /var/lib/mysql/            |
| innodb_data_home_dir      |                            |
| innodb_log_group_home_dir | ./                         |
| lc_messages_dir           | /usr/share/mysql/          |
| plugin_dir                | /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/     |
| slave_load_tmpdir         | /tmp                       |
| tmpdir                    | /tmp                       |
+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

As we can see from the above command, the **datadir** is present in `/var/lib/mysql`. Now, I needed to ensure that `/var` doesn't have enough space to accomodate the database in which case my detection is correct. I achieved it using the below command.

```
df -P /var | tail -1 | cut -d' ' -f 1
```

The above command basically tells the mount point of a particular directory. As I suspected, the mount point was under `/dev/sda2` which had only **40 GB** space. Now, changing the datadir is straightforward.

Stop the mysql service using,

```
service mysqld stop
```

Edit the file `/etc/my.cnf` to have the **datadir** to some partition where we have enough space.  (This is for RHEL and may vary depending on the OS Version). After changing the **datadir**, restart the mysql service using the command,

```
service mysqld start
```

**References**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968287/how-to-find-the-mysql-data-directory-from-command-line-in-windows

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274354/how-to-find-out-mount-partition-a-directory-or-file-is-on-linux-server

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can change the location where MySQL database data resides by changing the datadir variable in `/etc/my.cnf`.

*Make sure to backup your data prior to attempting below steps.*

1. Stop the mysqld service (`systemctl mysqld stop`).
2. Edit `/etc/my.cnf` and change the datadir variable to the location you would like (`datadir='insert_path_to_new_location'`), and make sure to note the previous location for the next step few steps.
3. Copy the data from the old datadir location to the new location.
4. Start the mysqld service (`systemctl mysqld start`).
5. Validate the mysqld service is working properly from the new location.
6. Clean up cruft in old datadir!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the location where a MySQL database by changing resides using a setting in the my.cnf file.

Comment: While this provides an answer to the *literal* question ("is it possible?" "yes"), it would be helpful if you also include information on which settings should be changed to achieve the desired effect.